# How to update to GHC 8.0

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to use the Quantum Programming language Quipper, and I am running into issues due to the version of GHC I am using:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ apt-show-versions ghc
ghc:amd64/xenial 7.10.3-7 uptodate
ghc:i386 not installed
```

As it turns out, 7.10 is the only version that Quipper cannot compile with.

I then discovered that apparently the [only way](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5ovvsw/how_to_get_haskell_8_on_ubuntu_1604/) to install Haskell 8.0 was using haskell-stack. Ok, I've never installed something on a stack, so this will go over well.

So I used the instructions on [this website](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#linux) to install haskell-stack, then ran the commands:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ stack setup
root@ubuntu:~$ stack update
root@ubuntu:~$ stack install ghc
```

The last command returned the following:

```
Didn't see ghc-8.0.2 in your package indices.
Updating and trying again.
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                  Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                    Downloading timestamp
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                                Downloading snapshot
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                                    Updating index   
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                                Updated package list downloaded
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpc                                                                                    Populated index cache.    
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: ghc-8.0.2
Perhaps you meant AAI, AAI, AAI, AES, AES, AES, AES, AES, AES, or AES?
```

So, a quick check again:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ apt-show-versions ghc
ghc:amd64/xenial 7.10.3-7 uptodate
ghc:i386 not installed
```

Nope, still 7.10. Tried also to download the package from [this website](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_2.html). The package failed to be extracted, so that's a good sign. Rinsed and repeated the above commands, and still nothing. Then I edited the stack.yaml file to say:

```
resolver: lts-9.14
resolver: ghc-8.0.2
```

Did absolutely nothing. What step am I missing? Its frustrating when people basically say "the stack does everything for you" and I'm like "what exactly am I supposed to do?"

**EDIT**

As I said above, downloading the package for 8.0.2 from haskell.org gives fails to extract the archive:

[image: Failure message of archive extraction]

Comment: Why do you think stack is the only way? The question you linked to doesn't say that.

Comment: What do you mean by "failed to be extracted"? And why do you think any of this is going to affect apt's package database?

Comment: melponene the question I linked said:
`Use stack (second option on the haskell.org website) and it will do the work for you.` and `Please use stack and not the Haskell Platform.` and `Assuming there's not already a PPA for it, use stack. In fact, unless the PPA is from someone you trust with root privileges, probably better to use stack (as a less privileged user).` and the OP then said `I got it working with stack. Thanks everyone.` If there is ANY other way to update to ghc-8.0.2, i would *love* to not have to use stack

Comment: Just download the binary from ghchq.

Comment: All I want is to update my GHC to 8.0. Idc about stack except as a means to an end.

Comment: DeBuisson this [website?](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_2.html) Once I have it, (which has its own problem above) how would it be installed? Just regular sudo apt-get?

Comment: @NathanGoedeke There is no .deb from ghchq so you don't use apt/apt-get to install it.  If you aren't familiar with autotools, config and makefiles then perhaps you should use hvr's ppa which I linked in my answer.

Comment: `stack install ghc` is definitely not the right way to install a particular compiler version (nor is that in the instructions you said you were following). It also seems like the output you posted is possibly for `stack install ghc-8.0.2`

Comment: jberry Its clearly from my lack of experience, but the instructions I gave just end with "you can now run with `stack`" leaving me to randomly guess how I'm supposed to get from there to ghc-8.0, which is literally all I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't jump into installing the binaries directly. While, as others mentioned, stack isn't the only way, it is certainly one of the easier ones.

So first thing, `stack setup` actually downloads GHC for you based on the resolver it finds. If you are not in a stack project, it'll default to the global stack config. On the other hand `stack install` is used for installing packages. That means doing `stack install ghc` is trying to look for a *package* on stackage that's called ghc, of which I don't think there are any.

**To run the GHC that stack installed**, you'll do `stack ghc` and to get a GHCi session, `stack ghci` (generally just prefix with stack).

You could also run the general `stack exec -- ..` to run a command with stack's path variables. E.g. `stack exec -- ghci` will work here as well, or `stack exec -- ghc --version` to get the GHC version.

Comment: Ok, so how would I do something like cabal install for this ghc?

Comment: You’ll use `stack install` more or less the same way you use `cabal install`. The main difference you’ll be concerned with is that stack looks at stackage.org for its packages, under whichever resolver you have specified (e.g. lts-9.11). Cabal installs directly from hackage.org, from which the packages on stackage is just a subset of these that are guaranteed to compile together. If you need to install packages not there, you can either get the source for them and run `stack install` inside them, or read up on the stack documentation a bit to see how it’s used :)

Comment: I think for Quipper, without knowing it, you’ll run it as `stack exec — quipper`, which lets quipper find the GHC in stack’s path.

Answer (score 1):

Binary distributions of GHC can be obtained from [GHC HQ](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/):

- 8.0.2 here https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_0_2.html#binaries
- 8.2.2 here https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_2_2.html#binaries

Any suggestion that any one tool is necessary to obtain GHC is wrong.

EDIT: On a nix computer, for example, one can do the following (approx, not tested):

```
wget https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2/ghc-8.2.2-x86_64-deb8-linux.tar.xz
tar xJf ghc-8.2.2*
cd ghc*
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make install
```

If you don't like portable shell and really want to use apt then consider using [hvr's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) which is pretty darn popular.

Comment: So I added the repository, and added the lines to  `sources.list` as per the instructions in the PPA link you gave, followed by an apt-get update. Then re-installed GHC. I went through all the commands you gave you as well, and by the ghc-8.2 folder on my home directory I can see that it was successful. 
Now what? If I compile in Quipper as I said in the OP, I get this error: `./quipper: 59: ./quipper: ghc: not found`. Re-installing GHC is still version 7.10.3. What do I do now?

Comment: The commands I gave you are for installing it to your home directory with the binary probably at `$HOME/local/bin`. If you aren't familiar with system administration then you are much better off using the PPA - uninstall any existing GHC and install hvr's ppa.  I can't help you with quipper as I've not used it nor know how it finds binaries.

Comment: My point is I tried the PPA first (added repository, edited sources.list, updated), and not seeing any results I tried the other way too. Quipper is just a shell file, including a shell command to invoke ghc. What would I have to do (in either solution) to be able to recognize ghc as a viable shell command?